# how can I loop through search function - python

Tags: python, loops, dictionary

I am trying to make search program but I stuck in some loop part.
There are several steps for function works.
First, I will get a word(input) from users.
Then, I will compare whether user's inputs are included in any values from any dictionary
If user's inputs are included, then I want to print out the key value from dictionary as list type. If not, then I want to execute the loop and print out some messages.

For example, if I type nice as input, then program should print matthew as list type.
Program should keep loop until I type the input that doesn't invovled in the dictionary value.
For example, if i type any input from dic_1 and dic_2, the program should keep loop until i input input that is not involved in the dictionary value.

If I type trash or something that is not in the dictionary, then program should print out messages that nothing match.

```
dic_1 = {'matthew':'he is a nice guy', 'dennis':'he is a bad guy', 'alex':'he is a good guy'}
dic_2 = {'manchester': 'city from england', 'tokyo':'city from japan', 'rome':'city from italy'}

def searchWords(*dicts):
  while(True):
     list_1 = []
     t = input('Enter a word for search:')
     for dic in dicts:
        for k,v in dic.items():
           if t in v:
              list_1+=[k]
          else:
              print("Nothing match, end program")
              break
    return list_1

print(searchWords(dic_1, dic_2)
```

Now on, I have no problem for print out key value when I input once but I get stuck on loop part.
I want to keep loop thorugh the program until I input words that not invovled in dictionary value but I can't figure out any algorithms for solving loop issue. I try out for for loop and if loop but I failed it. So if you guys can give any advice or idea for loop, it would be appreciate it lots.

Comment: I think you just need to shift the `return list_1` to the left(indent it to the same level) and it should solve your loop exiting

Comment: My biggest problem is that loop is not even start. It just work at once... I try shift to left but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to handle this is with a True/False flag as follows:

```
dic_1 = {'matthew': 'he is a nice guy',
         'dennis': 'he is a bad guy',
         'alex': 'he is a good guy'}
dic_2 = {'manchester': 'city from england',
         'tokyo': 'city from japan',
         'rome': 'city from italy'}


def searchWords(*dicts):
    while True:
        t = input('Enter a word for search: ')
        found = []
        for dic in dicts:
            for k, v in dic.items():
                if t in v.split():
                    found.append(k)
        if not found:
            print('No match')
            break
        else:
            print(*found)
```

Comment: Your way was helped me to get a loop  but what I want is that directly get a result when I input the value. For example:                                                                                                                  Enter a word for: bad                                                                                                                          ['dennis']                                                                                                                                                 I want to show results directly one by one.

Comment: @csdh I'm confused now. Please explain why you were constructing (appending to) a list in your original code

Comment: I want to print keys from the dictionaries until I input the values that doesn't match in the dictionaries. So if i input the values that is not on the dictionaries, program should print "nothing match" and then execute the loop.

Comment: @csdh Execute which program?

Comment: Because I want to print out the result as list type

Comment: Sorry, there was an misunderstanding. I just want to execute the loop.

Comment: @csdh I've edited my answer. Maybe that's what you wanted. If that doesn't work then I'm obviously not understanding you and I'll just delete it

Comment: No, that's what I wanted but I have a question. If I input guy, it prints:                                                               
[matthew]                                                                                                                      
[dennis]                                                                                                                                    [alex]

Comment: How can I print the keys that has the same value in common by one line?                                  Such as, if i input 'key', then it prints [matthew, dennis, alex] in one line

Comment: @csdh Edited (again and for the final time)